# .Net Core DBContext dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, thread-safety, dbcontext

I have refactored my code to try to avoid getting the error below as per the [MS Instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ie/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#avoiding-dbcontext-threading-issues) and other posts on this site, it seems to have improved slightly, but **if I have multiple button clicks in rapid succession I am still getting the error below**:

```
A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
```

**startup.cs**

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

**In My Controller:**

```
readonly RGWIncrementUserActionClicks RGWIncrementClicks = new();
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

public RGWController(IEmailSender emailSender, ApplicationDbContext context)
{
_emailSender = emailSender;
_context = context;
}

public async Task <IActionResult> RGWInsertNewActionNumber(int actionNumber)
{
string userId = ClaimsPrincipalExtensions.GetUserId<string>(User);

await RGWIncrementClicks.UserClick(actionNumber, userId, _context);

return RedirectToAction("RGW");
}
```

When `await RGWIncrementClicks.UserClick(actionNumber, userId, _context);` is triggered, the `UserClick` method (Not shown) has a switch statement which can call combinations of other methods to add values to the DB based on the `actionNumber` parameter passed in.

I tried with all subsequent methods and calls using await, but still get the multiple thread error. I also tried without them using await and still get the multiple thread error.

What I don't understand is that `await RGWIncrementClicks.UserClick(actionNumber, userId, _context);` is the point of entry to all subsequent functions that use dbContext, and it uses `await`, plus it is passing in the injected dbContext for this call instance, so how am I getting a threading error in subsequent functions...they should only trigger a second time after the await here for the entry point completes, indicating all subsequent functions are finished...no?

**Update:** I'm just thinking that I don't actually want this to be async, because I want the UI to update on each user click when the RedirectToAction triggers after the Database has been changed. So perhaps this is not a thread management issue, instead its a user management issue....I should prevent the user from clicking twice on any button that triggers my `RGWInsertNewActionNumber` method...

**Update.2 - I had left this out to save space:**

```
public class RGWIncrementUserActionClicks
{
private static readonly IncrementSiteActions _IncrementSiteActions = new();
private static readonly IncrementUserActions _IncrementUserActions = new();

public async Task UserClick(int actionNumber, string userId, ApplicationDbContext _context)
        {
var userActions = await _context.UserEnvironmentalActionCounts.FindAsync(userId);
var siteTotalActions = await _context.SiteEnvironmentalActionCounts.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

siteTotalActions.SiteGlobalWarmingClicks++;

switch (actionNumber)
{
case 1:

if (userActions != null)
{
await _IncrementUserActions.incrementUserActions(userId, userActions => { userActions.ReduceMeat++; userActions.UserReduceMeatCO2Total = userActions.UserReduceMeatCO2Total + 2.0075; }, userActions => { userActions.UserCO2Total = userActions.UserCO2Total + 2.0075; });

if (siteTotalActions != null)
{
await _IncrementSiteActions.incrementSiteActions(siteTotalActions => { siteTotalActions.SiteReduceMeat++; }, true, true, true);
}
else
{
await _context.SiteEnvironmentalActionCounts.AddAsync(new SiteEnvironmentalActionCounts { SiteTotal = 1, SiteGlobalWarmingTotal = 1, SiteReduceMeat = 1, SiteDeforestationTotal = 1, SiteExtinctionTotal = 1 });
}
}
else
{
await _context.UserEnvironmentalActionCounts.AddAsync(new UserEnvironmentalActionCounts { Id = userId, ReduceMeat = 1, UserTotal = 1, UserReduceMeatCO2Total = 2.0075, UserCO2Total = 2.0075 });

if (siteTotalActions != null)
{
await _IncrementSiteActions.incrementSiteActions(siteTotalActions => { siteTotalActions.SiteReduceMeat++; }, true, true, true);
}
else
{
await _context.SiteEnvironmentalActionCounts.AddAsync(new SiteEnvironmentalActionCounts { SiteTotal = 1, SiteGlobalWarmingTotal = 1, SiteReduceMeat = 1, SiteDeforestationTotal = 1, SiteExtinctionTotal = 1 });
}
}
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
break;

case 2:

...etc.

default:
break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error details:**

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
GatheringForGood.Areas.FunctionalLogic.IncrementUserActions.incrementUserActions(string userId, Action<UserEnvironmentalActionCounts> update, Action<UserEnvironmentalActionCounts> updateUserCO2Total) in IncrementUserActions.cs
+
23. await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
GatheringForGood.Areas.FunctionalLogic.RGWIncrementUserActionClicks.UserClick(int actionNumber, string userId, ApplicationDbContext _context) in RGWIncrementUserActionClicks.cs
+
30. await _IncrementUserActions.incrementUserActions(userId, userActions => { userActions.ReduceMeat++; userActions.UserReduceMeatCO2Total = userActions.UserReduceMeatCO2Total + 2.0075; }, userActions => { userActions.UserCO2Total = userActions.UserCO2Total + 2.0075; });
MyApp.Controllers.ReduceGlobalWarmingController.RGWInsertNewActionNumber(int actionNumber) in ReduceGlobalWarmingController.cs
+
            354. await RGWIncrementClicks.UserClick(actionNumber, userId, _context);
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
```

Comment: You have to show RGWIncrementClicks.UserClick at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to avoid multiple clicks on the UI layer using javascript. I had a small issue with this, but it was resolved. More info here if anyone else needs to prevent multiple UI clicks.

[JS function for a number of elements onclick without using getElementById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68896446/js-function-for-a-number-of-elements-onclick-without-using-getelementbyid/68896616#68896616)

Answer (score 1):

try to replace

```
private static readonly IncrementSiteActions _IncrementSiteActions = ....
private static readonly IncrementUserActions _IncrementUserActions = ....
```

with non static ones

```
private  readonly IncrementSiteActions _IncrementSiteActions = ....
private  readonly IncrementUserActions _IncrementUserActions = ....
```