# JS function for a number of elements onclick without using getElementById

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

.Net 5.0
Javascript

I have the below code to disable all elements on my UI when an image link `MouseClickIconRow1` or `MouseClickIconRow2` etc. is clicked.

However, I can't give all elements the same ID because my ID's are unique for UI testing.

I have tried to create a loop for `getElementsByName`, but I cant get it working. I have also been trying to pass in a unique element id as per below. I am pretty new to Javascript.

**HTML**

```
<img src="@Model.MouseClickIconThumbnailUrl" id="MouseClickIconRow1" name="IconClick" onclick="DisableEnableLinks(this, true)" width="20" height="35" alt="Mouse Click Here Image"></a>

<img src="@Model.MouseClickIconThumbnailUrl" id="MouseClickIconRow2" name="IconClick" onclick="DisableEnableLinks(this, true)" width="20" height="35" alt="Mouse Click Here Image"></a>
```

**Javascript**

```
function DisableEnableLinks(elem ,xHow) {
    document.getElementById(elem).onclick
        = function () {
            objLinks = document.links;
            for (i = 0; i < objLinks.length; i++) {
                objLinks[i].disabled = xHow;
                //link with onclick
                if (objLinks[i].onclick && xHow) {
                    objLinks[i].onclick =
                        new Function("return false;" + objLinks[i].onclick.toString().getFuncBody());
                }
                //link without onclick
                else if (xHow) {
                    objLinks[i].onclick = function () { return false; }
                }
                //remove return false with link without onclick
                else if
                    (!xHow && objLinks[i].onclick.toString().indexOf("function(){return false;}") != -1) {
                    objLinks[i].onclick = null;
                }
                //remove return false link with onclick
                else if (!xHow && objLinks[i].onclick.toString().indexOf("return false;") != -1) {
                    strClick = objLinks[i].onclick.toString().getFuncBody().replace("return false;", "")
                    objLinks[i].onclick = new Function(strClick);
                }
            }
        }
}
String.prototype.getFuncBody = function () {
    var str = this.toString();
    str = str.replace(/[^{]+{/, "");
    str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
    str = str.replace(/\n/gi, "");
    if (!str.match(/\(.*\)/gi)) str += ")";
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My HTML was incorrect. I needed to specify the unique id of each element as a string in the onclick.

```
onclick="DisableEnableLinks('MouseClickIconRow1', true)"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful:

```
var btnDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("btnContainer");
btnDiv[0].addEventListener("click", function() { console.log("Hello"); });

<div class="btnContainer">
    <input type="button" id="btn1" class="jsBtn" value="button1"/>
    <input type="button" id="btn2" class="jsBtn" value="button2"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `document.querySelectorAll()` function with appropriate selector and loop over the returned collection.

e.g.

```
document.querySelectorAll("img[name='IconClick']").forEach(function(el) {
    //do your stuff here... e.g.
    console.log(el.id);
})
```